# Setting relative paths in Dockerfile when building with ansible

Tags: ansible, dockerfile

I am trying to build some docker files using ansible, but it is not clear what is used as the build directory.

directory structure

```
.
├── build_images.yml
└── deploy
    ├── app_files
    │   └── requirements.txt
    └── dockerfiles
        └── app
            └── Dockerfile
```

I am running the `build_images.yml` playbook as follows (it picks up the correct path)

The `build_images.yml` file

```yaml
---                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  
  tasks:
    - name: Build container
       docker_image:
       name: app
       path: deploy/dockerfiles/app
       pull: no
       state: build
```

However, my Dockerfile contains

```
FROM base_image:latest

COPY ./deploy/app_files/requirements.txt requirements.txt
```

I have tried a few variations of the directory, but it keeps coming back with:

> no such file or directory

What is the appropriate base docker build directory to use for relative paths in the Dockerfile?

Comment: Can you remove the ./ From the COPY command. COPY commands copies the files considering the relative path so deploy/... Should work

Comment: I doubt it will since the path provides the context for the build and that the file will be outside so unreachable. My take below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extracts from the [docker_image documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/docker_image_module.html)

> path:
> Use with state 'present' to build an image. Will be the **path to a directory containing the context** and Dockerfile for building an image.

> dockerfile - added in 2.0: Use with state present to provide an alternate name for the Dockerfile to use when building an image.

I would then try

```yaml
- name: Build container
  docker_image:
    name: app
    path: deploy
    dockerfile: dockerfiles/app/Dockerfile
    pull: no
    source: build
```

And in your Dockerfile:

```
FROM base_image:latest

COPY app_files/requirements.txt requirements.txt
```

Note that your original path was wrong anyway (pointing to `dockerfiles` rather than `app_files`).

Comment: @Inian You are right, it was a typo after copy/pasting OP's example, but not exactly the one you thought.